# Rails error “NoMethodError” - Just started to use Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nomethoderror

Hopefully this is a very easy problem to solve as I am just starting out with Rails.

I have one database (Products) which contains a number of product attributes including brand, colour and product_type.

I currently have an index page (within productfinder directory) which is able to provide a summary of the products in the database.  I am using the following code in index.html.erb:

```
<% @distinctbrands.each do |distinctbrand| %>
  <h4><%= distinctbrand %></h4>
<% end %>
```

Within productfinder_controller.rb i have:

```
 def index
    @distinctbrands = Product.find( :all, :order => 'brand ASC', :select => 'brand' ).map{ |i| i.brand }.uniq
    @distinctcolours = Product.find( :all, :order => 'colour ASC', :select => 'colour' ).map{ |i| i.colour }.uniq
  end
```

UP TO THIS POINT EVERYTHING SEEMS TO BE WORKING CORRECTLY

Now I would like to add 3 buttons onto my index page, these buttons would enable the user to recalculate the distinctbrands and distinctcolours for a subset of the products - matching either product_type = "new" or "used".  The third button would correspond to the results not being filtered at all (i.e. as the index page loads initially).

In a previous question I was advised to add the following code:
In productfinder_controller:

```
before_filter :load_products, :only => [:index, :bybrand, :bycolour, :byprice]
protected

 def load_products
    @products = Product.by_product_type(params[:product_type])
  end
```

In Product.rb:

```
scope :by_product_type, lambda{  |product_type| where(product_type: product_type.to_i) unless product_type.nil? }
```

In index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "New", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :product_type => 'New' %>
<%= link_to "Used", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :product_type => 'Used' %>
<%= link_to "Don't Restrict", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :product_type => '' %>
```

When the application is now run I get a NoMethodError - ProductFinder#Index (while trying to do nil.each
The error is associated with <% @distinctbrands.each do |distinctbrand| %>

I wondered if the problem was with the functions defining @distinctbrands and @distinctcolours as the database has now been filtered, however I get the same error for both the following situations:

```
def index
  @distinctbrands = @product.find( :all, :order => 'brand ASC', :select => 'brand' ).map{ |i| i.brand }.uniq
  @distinctcolours = @product.find( :all, :order => 'colour ASC', :select => 'colour' ).map{ |i| i.colour }.uniq
end
```

and

```
def index
  @distinctbrands = Product.find( :all, :order => 'brand ASC', :select => 'brand' ).map{ |i| i.brand }.uniq
  @distinctcolours = Product.find( :all, :order => 'colour ASC', :select => 'colour' ).map{ |i| i.colour }.uniq
end
```

Is somebody able to provide me with a possible solution please?  Is the problem to do with @products not being defined within def index?  If so, how can this be done?

Many thanks for your time

Comment: The database doesn't get filtered, each query is individual and separate. What happens when you replace your @distinctbrands query with the following: @distinctbrands = ['a', 'b']. Do you still get the same error?

Answer (score 1):

Using the before_filter, you're creating an instance of @products, but your index is still loading @distinctbrands.

What I think you should do is:

1. Stick to one instance variable to load the
   products.
2. Add all the logic for
   adding the products to that variable
   in the before_filter and in your model.  Use scopes to make the queries chain-able (using Rails 3?)
3. Use a
   condition in the load_products method searching for a params
   hash to determine if the products
   should be loaded by the option set in the params,
   or just all.

So in your model, the load_products method could look like:

```
def load_products
  if params[:product_type]
    @products = Product.by_product_type(params[:product_type])
  else
    @products = Product.find( :all, :order => 'brand ASC', :select => 'brand' ).map{ |i| i.brand }.uniq
  end
end
```

Then in your index update to:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <h4><%= product.name %></h4>
<% end %>
```

I might be confused but I see a few different things here.  I see brand, color, and type.  What is the default view you want show?  If they are filtered by type, when does color come into play?

Comment: It seems to me that the OP wants to be able to view brands, colors and products on the same page and as separate queries.

Comment: Thanks both for your comments, sorry for not making the situation as clear as it could be.  By using the if statement within 'def load_grips', the index page loads initially with all the data in it (as I was hoping!).  However, when I click on any of the 3 buttons the products disappear (i.e. I assume they are all excluded).

Comment: Further to this, I am currently confused with regard to how functions are used within the controller.  It appears parameters calculated within 'def load grips' can be used by the index page as well as other pages? However, those parameters within 'def index' can ONLY be used on the index page - is this correct?  Secondly, when using the '.find' function, does this need to act on Product (i.e. it won't work on an instance variable?).

Comment: Finally, to answer your question regarding the information on the index page, the goal is...  Initially load the page with all products included - the page should give a list of all brands stocked and all colours stocked.  On clicking on the "New" button, I would like these 2 lists to be refreshed - i.e. provide a list of all brands stocked for "New" products as well as all colours for "New" products.  Similarly, "Used" button should refresh the lists and show the information for those just matching the "Used" criteria.  "Don't Restrict" should bring back the page as it was initially. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help - I went through your suggestions again and managed to identify that I had a minor error in product.rb, now it reads:

```
scope :by_product_type, lambda{|product_type| where(:product_type => product_type) unless product_type.nil? }
```

All seems to be working well!
Thanks again